# twistd.py log to both stdout and file

Tags: python, logging, twisted, twistd

I'm using `twistd.py` to run my application as follows:

```
twistd -noy -l logfile.log tacfile.tac
```

The unfortunate thing with this is that all output now goes to the log file, which is better for debugging things in the past but worse for debugging things in the present. I want the best of both worlds... how can I make `twistd` log to stdout as well as to the file provided in the command line?

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: @isedev: both linux and windows

Comment: not an answer but I usualy use tail-f logfile.log on an actively written to logfile to have those realtime viewing capabilites

Comment: @jbreicis: yeah i settled on `watch -n 0.5 tail -n 50 logfile.log` because the logfile keeps rotating every megabyte it takes up

Answer (score 1):

I'd try:

```
twistd -noy -l - tacfile.tac | tee logfile.log
```

"-l -" makes twistd log to stdout, tee saves it to the file and prints to stdout. On ubuntu tee comes from coreutils package.

<--- Edit below --->

If you want something only specific to twisted you can add the following code in the tac file:

```
from twisted.python import log, logfile

logFile = logfile.LogFile.fromFullPath('tacfile.log')
log.addObserver(log.FileLogObserver(logFile).emit)
```

and run twistd with "-l -"

Comment: I figured someone would mention `tee`, but this won't work on windows unless I install `tee` which I don't want to... is there any built-in python/twisted way?

Comment: I edited the response. I'm not sure it would work on windows, but it's worth a shot...